# Unable to send email via any of SMTP servers using an IP camera, why?

Tags: router, email, port-forwarding, smtp, vdsl

I'm trying to setup Mail Settings on my IP Camera, but none of the SMTP servers seem to work, and this is only happening when it's connected on my DSL connection! Otherwise it works great on my cable connection!

On DSL connection, if I click the "Test" button, it shows "Unable to determine remote server".

On Cable, "Test" button, shows "Successful" and the message is delivered.

Any idea what may be the problem?
Or how to fix it?

Could it be that the DSL modem is blocking SMTP ports?!

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried:
**smtp.live.com**(port 25 and 587), **smtp.gmail.com**(port 465, 587 and 25)
[image]

Comment: It very well could be a port blocked, try port 587 its a popular alternate to port 25.   Also whose SMTP server is it?  most require authentication period, and other require authentication if you are trying to send email from a different isp's connection.

Comment: I'm talking about smtp.live.com and smtp.gmail.com. And I actually tried ports 25, 587 and 465 but for some reason it only shows "Unable to determine remote server" message and fails to deliver!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the DSL provider is blocking SMTP ports due to spam concerns.

**Option 1:** See if there is an alternate port you can use with your SMTP server.

**Option 2:** Some ISPs only allow you to use SMTP through their e-mail service & SMTP server, so try setting that up and using that SMTP server. ([Source](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28027880-DSL-Which-SMTP-port-))

Comment: Option 1: Tried the alternate ports for smtp.live.com(25 and 587), smtp.gmail.com(25, 587 and 465) but no use. Option 2: Unfortunately I don't know if my ISP has SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I configured email photo/snapshot alerts with FOSCAM R2 cameras and it worked fine with GMAIL SMTP, however, I vaguely remember having to do something strange actually WITHIN GMAIL, something about permissions regarding one gmail account requiring permission from a different GMAIL account to send it messages automatically (it was very weird).

The settings were as follows:

- SMTP Server smtp.gmail.com
- SMTP Port: 587
- Transport Layer Security: STARTTLS
- Need authentication: Yes
- SMTP Username: <myemailaddress>@gmail.com
- SMTP Password: <myemailaddresspassword>
- Sender Email: <myemailaddress>@gmail.com>
- First Receiver: <adifferenemailaddress>@gmail.com
- Second Receiver: <anotherdifferentemailaddressnotgmailthough>

Also I think having the correct Primary DNS Server and secondary under Network->IP Configuration helps. Type `ipconfig /all` to get it from Windows on the command prompt.

Another strange thing is that I tried exactly the same config setting above with a camera from China (not FOSCAM) and it did NOT WORK, Gmail SMTP didn't work, BT Yahoo didn't work but strangely hotmail DID ! So god knows what's going on.

Also for my Chinese Camera (non FOSCAM) for the hotmail.com account STARTTLS Port: 25 and smtp.live.com worked fine for me with sender being my hotmail account and the receiver being my gmail account.